# query replace null values to data bigquery

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

Let's say I a have query

```
#standardSQL
SELECT a.person, score, dte
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Aaron' person UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Baron' person UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Cindy' person
)a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 'Aaron' person, 10 score, 20 dte UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Baron' person, 20 score, 20 dte UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Aaron' person, 10 score, 21 dte UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Cindy' person, 10 score, 21 dte UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Baron' person, 20 score, 21 dte
)b
on a.person = b.person
order by dte
```

The result is

```
Row person  score   dte  
1   Aaron   10      20   
2   Baron   20      20   
3   Aaron   10      21   
4   Baron   20      21   
5   Cindy   10      21
```

Now, can I have a data also of "Cindy" with 0 score and dte = 20?

so the expectation is:

```
Row person  score   dte  
1   Aaron   10      20   
2   Baron   20      20   
3   Cindy   0       20   
4   Aaron   10      21
5   Baron   20      21   
6   Cindy   10      21
```

It doesn't necessary to use left join. Basically, I only have 1  table but just want to have data of 0 for each dte and person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH persons AS (
  SELECT 'Aaron' person UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Baron' person UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Cindy' person UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mike' person
), scores AS (
  SELECT 'Aaron' person, 10 score, 20 dte UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Baron' person, 20 score, 20 dte UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Aaron' person, 10 score, 21 dte UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Cindy' person, 10 score, 21 dte UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Baron' person, 20 score, 21 dte
), dtes AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT dte 
  FROM scores
)
SELECT a.person, IFNULL(score, 0) score, d.dte
FROM persons a CROSS JOIN dtes d 
LEFT JOIN scores b 
ON a.person = b.person AND d.dte = b.dte
ORDER BY dte, person
```

with result as below

```sql
person   score    dte    
Aaron    10       20     
Baron    20       20     
Cindy    0        20     
Mike     0        20     
Aaron    10       21     
Baron    20       21     
Cindy    10       21     
Mike     0        21
```